# Proof that $\sqrt{n}\left( \hat{F}_n(x_1)-F(x_1),\dots,\hat{F}_n(x_k)-F(x_k)\right) \rightarrow \mathcal{N}_k(0,\Sigma)$

Tags: central-limit-theorem, asymptotics, order-statistics

By definition \begin{align*} \Sigma =  F(\min(x_i,x_j))-F(x_i)F(x_j)\end{align*}
Note: $\hat{F}_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n 1_{\{X_j \leq x\}}$

I think that $\mathbb{E}\left[\hat{F}_n(x_i)\right] = F(x_i)$.

Now considering \begin{align*}var\left(\hat{F}_n(x_i)\right) = \frac{1}{n^2} var\left(\sum_{u=1}^n 1_{\{X_u \leq x_i\}}\right) = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n cov\left(\sum_{u=1}^n 1_{\{X_u \leq x_i\}}, \sum_{u=1}^n 1_{\{X_u \leq x_j\}}\right)\end{align*} I get \begin{align*}\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{n}(F(\min(x_i,x_j))-F(x_i)F(x_j)))\end{align*}

I'm confused with the indexing and I'm not sure how to get to the final result.

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/385568/119261.